# How to find a generator matrix when codewords are given?

Tags: matrices, signal-processing

I do not understand how to determine a generator matrix. I have attached a question below. Can someone please explain to me how to do this question?

The vectors $C_0=[10001]$, $C_1=[11010]$, and $C_2=[11101]$ form a basis for a
$(5,3)$ block code $C$ over $\text{GF}(2)$.

Use $C_0$, $C_1$, and $C_2$ to construct a generator matrix $G$, and then
transform $G$ into systematic form $\tilde{G}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a generator matrix contains a basis of the code as row vectors:

$C = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&1\\ 1& 1&0&1&0\\ 1&1&1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}$

Now you can perform row operations to form a systematic code.